# Loading a class from XML with boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I'm trying to load a simple class from a XML file but getting the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'xml >> boost::serialization::make_nvp(const
char*, T&) [with T = Options](((Options&)(& o)))'
```

It must be something stupid I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out what. Does someone have an idea? Here's my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>

class Options {
public:
    Options() {
        SetInteger("screenWidth", 1024);
        SetInteger("screenHeight", 768);
    }
    void SetInteger(const std::string& name, int value) {
        integers_[name] = value;
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, int> integers_;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class archive>
    void serialize(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
        ar & make_nvp("integers", integers_);
    }
};

int main() {
    Options o;
    std::ofstream ifs("input.xml");
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive xml(ifs);
    xml >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("options", o); // error
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well from your code and what you are writing it would result you are trying to read. In this case you shouldn't use ofstream and xml_oarchive but **ifstream** and **xml_iarchive**.

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

....

//for read
std::ifstream ifs("input.xml");
boost::archive::xml_iarchive xmlIn(ifs);
xmlIn >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("options", o); 

//for write
std::ofstream ofs("output.xml");
boost::archive::xml_oarchive xmlOut(ofs);
xmlOut << boost::serialization::make_nvp("options", o);
```